# Как вернуться к первому элементу RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android

Как вернуться в начало списка, который находится в адаптере для RecyclerView?

Предположим я дошел до 100-го элемента и хочу вернуться в самое начало и чтобы не скролить вручную, я нажимаю на всплывающую кнопку и в этот же момент оказываюсь в начале

Answer (score 3, accepted):

recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает